# Flashing system.img using terminal

Tags: android

How to flash system in android if there are more than 1 system.img files. I want to flash stock rom but there are 45 system.img files (system_1.img to system_45.img).
and is it ok if i just flash recovery, syatem, boot and splash?

Comment: This is more Android related rather than Ubuntu related, try rebooting into bootloader and runnin `fastboot flash recovery <yout_boot.img>` and continue from there.

Comment: @Yaron I know about that but the problem is there are 45 system.img files and i can't find a way to flash them all at once. There is no flash_all.sh files otherwise it would have been easy

Comment: I don't think that this is how it works, where did you get so many files from?

Comment: @Yaron I downloaded stock rom for my android. The developer has provided QcomDloader app to flash the rom. But it is windows software and I only have linux at this moment. I searched a little bit about this and found that "fastboot flashall" command works for this but there must exist a file named androidinfo.txt which is not there in zip i downloaded. I think developer only considered windows for this. :-p

Comment: It might be a special setting because fastboot also supports offset, meaning that I can select several img files and write them to different locations in recovery, if you can detect what exactly the developer is doing then you can possible trace back the process, otherwise it's going to be very tricky.